# Using vite to build a react project, the hot update failure problem after using mobx in the project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx-react, vite

[image]

Home.tsx，Page effect

[image]

Modify the Home component and save it.

[image]
[image]

And the terminal console can see the update of hmr, but the page effect has not changed, and the console.log in the Home component has not been triggered.

Comment: If the observer is removed, the hot update of vite will take effect.

Comment: Please do not use imgur, but simply paste the code here.